# CSS3 + HTML5SHIV + CSS3PIE Border-radius NOT working on IE8 but working on IE7,9,10

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css3pie, html5shiv

the site I'm working with - http://www.quickseorankings.com/dev/, its built with:

- Twitter Bootstrap
- HTML5 + CSS3
- HTML5SHIV
- CSS3PIE

**Issue:** Border-radius at navbar link(active) NOT working on IE8 even with CSS3PIE. But its working on IE7,9,10 (using browserstack for testing)

**CSS Location:** */css/* 
**CSS3PIE HTC File Location:** */root/* same location as my index.html

**HTC Coded as:** `behavior: url(PIE.htc);`

---

**Fix Attempt #1:** `behavior: url(/PIE.htc);` and `behavior: url(../PIE.htc);`
even tried using the php one - `behavior: url(PIE.php);` `behavior: url(/PIE.php);`
**Fix Attempt #2**Added Htaccess: `AddType text/x-component .htc` 
**Fix Attempt #3** used: `http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/` - its actually a an HTC solutions but different approach vs CSS3PIE. Still didn't work..

**Fix Attempt #4** Added: `-pie-border-radius: 10px;` not working.
**Fix Attempt #5** Added: `position:relative !important; zoom:1; z-index:0 !important` nothing...

---

Followed other fix on this forum, still didn't work.. Greatly appreciate your help!

**Fix Suggestion by ScottSimpson:** Isolation test, with plain html with no TBS, here-s the page test - `http://www.quickseorankings.com/pie/` the ones on the top button is CSS3PIE (DIDN'T WORK).. The bottom part button from fetchak ie-css.htc is quite working.. Now, this lead us near to my problem.. Question is, is TBS causing .htc not to load properly? or TBS is overwriting it? but I did, !important with the values..hmmmm..

**WINNER IS pjumble** : I'm using PIE.htc (PIE 2.0 beta 1) so it needs to have this file - `PIE_IE678.js` then everything's working... Thank you so much pjumble!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is far from my area of expertise, but hopefully others will be able to help. What was the fix you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Thank you Jerry. I tried absolute path url for the htc location quote and without quote. Tried (/PIE.htc) an (PIE.htc).. I also tried (PIE.php) still the same..tried placing the htc and pie.php in my /pie/ folder, didn't work.. I know there's a different solution/workaround for border-radius in ie8 like the jquery corner js, but I want to solve this first..

Comment: Try creating a new html page without TBS, and with only a rounded corner element. That way you can see if TBS is causing the issue with PIE. IMO - PIE is more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: With the PIE 2.0 beta you need PIE_IE678.js on your server, and you need to tell PIE where it is either by adding a pie-load-path attribute to the html element, or using an absolute URL in your stylesheet to the HTC file [(see source)](https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/blob/master/sources/htc_script.js#L37). Alternatively stick to using the PIE 1.0 stable which works without external javascript files.

Comment: @ScottSimpson thanks. The isolation process lead us to the answer - here's the test http://www.quickseorankings.com/pie/ . CSS3PIE didn't work at all. However, fetchak ie-css.htc working 100%. Question is, why fetchak didn't work with TBS?

Comment: @pjumble I will just call PIE_1E678.js in my script tag and that's it right? or this pie-load-path <-- can you cite some example? is this absolute path of my .htc? Elaborate pls. thanks btw..

Comment: @pjumble tried your suggestion on quickseorankings.com/pie/ didn't work.. All I did was download that htc_script.js and call it `<script src="htc_script.js"></script>` didn't work. However, I'm confused with the pie-load-path.. do I need to fill in the absolute url path of my PIE.htc here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using PIE 2.0 beta, the `.htc` file for PIE 2.0 simply loads an external javascript file `PIE_IE678.js`. You need to upload `PIE_IE678.js` to your server and then inform PIE where the javascript file is located.

The easiest way is to add the `PIE_IE678.js` file to the same directory as `PIE.htc` and then use the *absolute* URL to the PIE.htc file in your css file, e.g:

```
behavior: url('http://www.quickseorankings.com/dev/PIE.htc');
```

and your directory structure would need to be:

```
quickseorankings.com/
   dev/
      PIE.htc
      PIE_IE678.js
```

Note: Don't manually load any of the PIE .js files, the .htc file loads the additional javascript files for you.

Comment: Followed the above answer and updated the /dev/ this is the error it gets:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Sat, 18 May 2013 21:44:53 UTC


Message: 'element' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.quickseorankings.com/dev/htc_script.js

Comment: You're uploading the wrong file (I only linked that file in the comment to show how PIE tries to locate the javascript). Go to http://css3pie.com/download/, download PIE 2.0 beta 1, unzip, upload `PIE.htc` and `PIE_IE678.js` to your `dev` folder, then in your `ie8.css` file load the htc using the behavior listed above (using the absolute URL). Don't manually include any extra files.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can add quite similar question here. CSS3PIE says they support box-shadow, how will we code it in pie? tried -pie-box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 3px #999; didn't work, tried rgba mode, didn't work.. have you @pjumble successfully rendered inset shadow with pie?

Comment: @bootstrapper unfortunately PIE doesn't support `inset` with `box-shadow` - see: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/3